# AS400 SQL Database Query

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400, sql-date-functions

The time column has a string type containing a time in the format HHMMSS. Sample data is:

```
95030    
122030
132030
```

As you can see, there are no leading zeros.

I am trying to extract the above values and convert them to something like below

```
95030 -> 9:50:30
122030 -> 12:20:30
```

The Sql Query:

```
select cast(Left(TIMECOLUMN, 1,1)||':'||substring(TIMECOLUMN,2,2)||':'||substring(TIMECOLUMN, 4,2) as string) 
from DBNAME.TABLENAME LIMIT 5;
```

The Above query can perform only below,

```
95030 -> 9:50:30
```

How would I perform:

```
122030 -> 12:20:30
```

In the same query without having to run a different query?

Thank you all in Advance!

Comment: Is there a way to use LEN() function, determine its length and perform the Action?

Comment: Do you care if there is a leading '0'?

Comment: No Strom, I can have 95030 -> 09:50:30, This works for me.

Comment: What about 09:05:03? Is it stored as 953 or 90503?

Comment: Only Leading char 0 is missing, for other cases zero is present, like this: 90504.

Comment: @Satya, I am taking my previous comment back, I found some Dates has only 3 Characters like 953.

Comment: If  any one of the  three parts (hours, minutes, seconds) can be single digits, there is no reliable way to decode string to get time.  9123 can be either 09:12:03 or 09:01:23. 11111 can be either 01:11:11 or 11:01:11. You should check with developers for programs that are inserting/updating records.

Comment: Based on other comments, it looks like formula used is (hours * 10000) + (minutes * 100 ) + seconds. If this is  the formula,  second solution given by @Dinu (using mod) is better option.

Answer (score 2):

In DB2, you could use `TO_DATE()` (which is a handy alias to [`TIMESTAMP_FORMAT()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzscatsformat.htm)) to convert the string to a date, and `TO_CHAR()` (aka [`VARCHAR_FORMAT()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzscavarcharformat.htm)) to format it:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(timecolumn, 'HH24MISS'), 'HH24:MI:SS') FROM DBNAME.TABLENAME LIMIT 5
```

[The documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/de/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007107.html) states that missing leading zeros are supported:

> A substring of the string-expression representing a component of a timestamp (such as year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds) can include less than the maximum number of digits for that component of the timestamp indicated by the corresponding format element. Any missing digits default to zero. For example, with a format-string of `'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'`, an input value of `'999-3-9 5:7:2'` would produce the same result as `'0999-03-09 05:07:02'`.

---

As commented by @Dinu and @jmarkmurphy, this might fail because of the fact that time parts are not separated. In that event, an alternative approach is to manually add the missing trailing `0`(s) before conversion.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
    TO_DATE(
        RIGHT('000000' || timecolumn, 6),
        'HH24MISS'
    ),
    'HH24:MI:SS') 
FROM DBNAME.TABLENAME LIMIT 5
```

Comment: So the above can handle both Scenarios?
122030 -> 12:20:30
and 
95030 -> 09:50:30 convert them to a String?

Comment: @Pavan_Obj: as per the documentation: yes. I would be interested to know if this works for you (I do not have access to a db2 database to check).

Comment: The problem is, because the source format has no separators such as `:` it might be that the parser doesn't know which component is missing digits. So at least it should be left-padded with `0` before feeding into this.

Comment: I agree with Dinu, use `right('0' || TIMECOLUMN, 6)` instead of `timecolumn`, to be on the safe side. My 400 takes 45 minutes to IPL, so I can't test quickly.

Comment: @Dinu: you might be right - I tested on Oracle and an error happens when the leading 0 is missing (while when separators exist in the string to parse, it works). I updated my answer with a solution for that.

Comment: I will try and get back here, thank you all. Sincerely Appreciate you all.

Comment: Instead of `right('0' || timecolumn, 6)`, I would use `right('000000' || timecolumn, 6)` to handle times around midnight properly. I suspect the '952' mentioned above would not be 9:5:2, but 00:09:52.

Comment: It does work with the addition of code by @jmarkmurphy.  The links however are for z/OS, not IBM i, as indicated in the tags.

Comment: Here are the appropriate links for IBM i - [TIMESTAMP_FORMAT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzscatsformat.htm) and [VARCHAR_FORMAT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzscavarcharformat.htm). **TO_DATE** and **TO_CHAR** are alternate syntaxes respectively.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>`TO_DATE()` is not available on Db2 for IBM i...</strike>
**Apparently it is available, but only documented in the SQL reference as syntax alternative under the TIMESTAMP_FORMAT() function**

`TIMESTAMP_FORMAT()` is (assuming you are on a currently supported release)

However, it requires the leading zero for 95030...

The following will work

```
select char(time(timestamp_format(right('0' concat timecolumn ,6),'HH24MISS')))
from DBNAME.TABLENAME
```

Comment: Though undocumented, `TO_DATE` appears to be a synonym for `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` on my 7.2 box.

Comment: Likewise `TO_CHAR` is a syntax alternative to `VARCHAR_FORMAT`. I like the `TO_DATE`, and `TO_CHAR` variants better, they are more concise.

Answer (score -1):

- Use `Right` instead of `Left`. Right-based position is fixed.

or

- Use SUBSTR with negative index. Negative index means from the right. I.e. `SUBSTR(X,-2,2)` is seconds, `SUBSTR(X,-4)` is hours.

or

- Treat it as an integer and use i.e. MOD(X,100) for secs, MOD(FLOOR(X/100),100) for mins etc

or

- if @Strom is right and SUBSTR doesn't allow negative index - just prepend `LEN()`: `SUBSTR(X,LENGTH(X)-2,2)` => seconds

Comment: SUBSTR cannot have a negative index in DB2. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_substr.html